# How to display multiple values from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

my array has 2 elements. I'm creating a dynamic list using the "Name" and displaying the "Location" while submitting. But I also want to display the "ID" while submitting.

JS Code create a dynamic list using **Name** - **ITC, JOY** When I chose **ITC**, I want to display **India** and **100**. But this code only allow me to choose ***single value from the array***.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

var Comp = [
{Name: "ITC"    , Location: "India ", ID:   "100"   },
{Name: "JOY"    , Location: "US "   ,ID:    "200"  },
];
var AllCustomers = document.getElementById("AllCustomers");

for (var i = 0; i < Comp.length; i++) {
             var My_list = document.createElement("OPTION");                      
             My_list.innerHTML = Comp[i].Name;
             My_list.value = Comp[i].Location;
             AllCustomers.appendChild(My_list)

}
function ShowCX()
{
          document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML=AllCustomers.value;
          document.getElementById("display_message2").innerHTML=AllCustomers.value;

}

</script>
</head>
<select id="AllCustomers">
    </select>

<input type="button" onclick="ShowCX()" value="submit" />


<p> Location:  <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
<p> ID:  <span id = "display_message2"></span> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your array only has two elements?

Comment: my array has 3 elements. I'm creating a dynamic list using the "Name" and displaying the "Location" while submitting. But I also want to display the "ID".

Comment: Your `Comp` array has two elements. Each element is an object with three properties. Perhaps it might help if you showed what you want the result to look like

Comment: This is my HTML code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

</script>
</head>
<select id="AllCustomers">
    </select>

<input type="button" onclick="ShowCX()" value="submit" />


<p> Location:  <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
<p> ID:  <span id = "display_message2"></span> </p>
</body>

</html>

Comment: You already know how to edit your question. Please put your code in there. Also, what do you want the HTML to look like **after** your script runs. How do you want to display and use the `ID` properties?

Comment: JS Code create a dynamic list using **Name** - ITC, JOY
When I chose **ITC**, I want to display **India** and **100**. But this code only allow me to choose single value from the array.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61076989/edit) and put all of the above in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. What I did is I stored an Object with the Location and ID in the value attribute and accessed it when it was selected. There are many ways to do this though. Also I changed the for loop for better abstraction.

```js
var Comp = [{
    Name: "ITC",
    Location: "India ",
    ID: "100"
  },
  {
    Name: "JOY",
    Location: "US ",
    ID: "200"
  },
];
var AllCustomers = document.getElementById("AllCustomers");

/*for (var i = 0; i < Comp.length; i++) {
  var My_list = document.createElement("OPTION");
  My_list.innerHTML = Comp[i].Name;
  My_list.value = Comp[i].Location;
  AllCustomers.appendChild(My_list)

}*/
Comp.forEach(element=>{
  var My_list = document.createElement("OPTION");
  My_list.innerHTML = element.Name;
  My_list.value = JSON.stringify({"loc":element.Location,"id":element.ID});//storing as a JSON in value attribute
  AllCustomers.appendChild(My_list)
})

function ShowCX() {
  value = JSON.parse(AllCustomers.value); //gettinng the JSON
  document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = value.loc;
  document.getElementById("display_message2").innerHTML = value.id;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
  </head>
  <select id="AllCustomers">
  </select>

  <input type="button" onclick="ShowCX()" value="submit" />


  <p> Location: <span id="display_message"></span> </p>
  <p> ID: <span id="display_message2"></span> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected index of the  by using its selectedIndex property that way you can dynamically display your values based on user input. I've also added in the id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <select id="AllCustomers"></select>
    <input type="button" onclick="ShowCX()" value="submit" />
    <p> Location: <span id="display_message"></span> </p>
    <p> ID: <span id="display_message2"></span> </p>

    <script language="JavaScript">

    var Comp = [
        { Name: "ITC", Location: "India ", ID: "100" },
        { Name: "JOY", Location: "US ", ID: "200" },
    ];
    var AllCustomers = document.getElementById("AllCustomers");

    for (var i = 0; i < Comp.length; i++) {
        var My_list = document.createElement("OPTION");
        My_list.innerHTML = Comp[i].Name;
        My_list.value = Comp[i].Location;
        My_list.id = Comp[i].ID;
        AllCustomers.appendChild(My_list)

    }
    function ShowCX() {
        var selectedIndex = document.getElementById("AllCustomers").selectedIndex
        document.getElementById("display_message").innerHTML = AllCustomers[selectedIndex].value; document.getElementById("display_message2").innerHTML = AllCustomers[selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById("display_message2").innerHTML = AllCustomers[selectedIndex].value; document.getElementById("display_message2").innerHTML = AllCustomers[selectedIndex].id;
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("display_message2").innerHTML=Comp[AllCustomers.selectedIndex].ID;`